# Create anchor tag within unordered list elements with d3js?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I wanted to dynamically create anchor tags within an undordered list:

Mannually this works:

```
<h2>
Without d3
</h2>
  <ul id="anotherList">
    <li>
      <a href="http://www.google.com">
      <text>hello</text></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://www.google.com">
      <text>hello</text></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://www.google.com">
      <text>hello</text></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://www.google.com">
      <text>hello</text></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://www.google.com">
      <text>hello</text></a>
    </li>

  </ul>
```

So, the HTML structure built by d3 should look like the example above. My d3 code looks like this:

```
var data = [1,2,3,4,5];

d3.select("#divListElement")
.selectAll("li")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("li")
  .append("a")
  .attr("xlink:href", "http://www.google.de")
  .append("text")
      .text("hello");
```

When I inspect the DOM structure of both, I see that they are indeed the same. However the example without d3 (manually created) works, while the example with d3 does not work, even though it's the same structure?

http://jsfiddle.net/thadeuszlay/Qh9X5/9211/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xlink:href is meant for svg use (though it looks like it might be deprecated), if you are adding an href to an a tag just use `href` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href

`.attr("href", "http://www.google.de")`